# How to use 100 percent of the raspberry pi cpu in C programs?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I wrote a long c program.
When I ran the program on the raspberry pi,  I've seen that the cpu used in 25 percent.
The execution time was 50 seconds, it is to long for my app.
My question is: What do I need to do in order to use 100 percent of the cpu
when I want to execute computer programs?

Comment: It is normally the other way 'round: you write a program and wonder why it it uses 100%. Your question does not make much sense. Write the code you need for your application. If it runs fast enough, it's fine.Oh, and: which RasPi? There are at least two very different models. I'd somehow suspect your "25%" **is** in fact 100% CPU load.

Comment: Are you trying to overheat the CPU (ie: like CPUBurnIn tests or SuperPI)? Are you trying to prioritize CPU timeslices for your program because it's a high priority program?

Comment: You're probably using 100% of one CPU but the Pi 3 (if you're using that) has four CPUs. So your question is how to use more than one CPU, right?

Comment: I removed the audio tag because it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi has several cores. If you have 4 cores on your CPU, than a single threaded program will only be able to consume 25% of the CPU.

In order to reach the other 75% you need to either use multiple threads in your application, or run the application several times simultaneously so that the kernel process scheduler can utilize the full capabilities of the CPU.

If possible, try running the application 4 times at once, and you should see 100% CPU utilization as an example.

Comment: The Pi1 and zero have only one core, IIRC. Adn we don't know how OP measures the load.

Comment: @Olaf True. But this is definitely the simplest possible explanation for seeing exactly 25% CPU utilization.

Comment: Yes, but the question is too unclear to be answered. It is not even clear why OP wants to see 100% load. Normally one wants to **minimise** the CPU load.